# Problem with running buildroot generated raspberry image on Qemu

Tags: embedded-linux, qemu, buildroot

I have build Linux image using buildroot for raspberryp pi 3, using the instruction ([Link](https://www.thirtythreeforty.net/posts/2020/01/mastering-embedded-linux-part-3-buildroot/)).
When I run the image in Qemu I am facing the problem:

[image]

Please, advice how i can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line is using qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc, which is telling QEMU to emulate an x86 PC. That is not a Raspberry Pi and it cannot run the Arm code that a Pi needs.

You've also given a URL to a google search, not a set of build instructions, so it's difficult to see what you were trying to follow.

Looking at the instructions in your updated link, they give several possible configs: "Raspberry Pi Zero W", "Raspberry Pi Zero" and "Virtual machine". None of those is a Pi 3, so what config are you actually building ? Unless you've built the "Virtual machine" config (which is an x86-64 one) the QEMU command line you're using won't work. The command line you're using also does not match the one in the blog post, which uses `output/images/bzImage` for its kernel, not a `zImage` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited URL accordingly